# What is 'plexus' and how is it related to maven?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, plexus

Can someone explain to me what Plexus is [http://plexus.codehaus.org/](https://web.archive.org/web/20150526011538/http://plexus.codehaus.org/) ?

How is it related to Maven?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/from-plexus-to-guice-1-why-guice/). Its root comming from IoC for Maven in later days it has been replaced (more or less) by guice.

Comment: "The Plexus project provides a full software stack for creating and executing software projects. Based on the Plexus container, the applications can utilise component-oriented programming to build modular, reusable components that can easily be assembled and reused." Maven software is made using [plexus framework](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/) to avoid reinventing the wheel for using dependency injection, component dependencies and config, auto-wiring, lifecycles, nested containers e.t.c . e.g. Other software are made using [Spring framework](https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Plexus is a platform consisting of [an Inversion-of-Control container](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-containers/) along with a number of utility libraries, including the [Classworlds](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-classworlds/) class loader framework. Maven was built on it but, as khmarbaise points out, a large amount of work has gone into [replacing it with Guice](https://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/from-plexus-to-guice-1-why-guice/).

Plexus also provides a [number of utility libraries](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/) which are heavily used by the core Maven plugins -- `plexus-utils`, `plexus-archiver` and more. `~/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/` will be fairly busy on any machine that's run Maven.